# Invalid Dimensions Error MatplotLib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to image work in `Python` and am struggling to get an image to show using `matplotlib`.

The problem:

I have a numpy array, of shape `(3072, )`. I recognize that this array represents an image that should have 3 channels (RGB) and images of 32x32 pixels. As such, I reshaped the image into `(3, 32, 32)` shape.

```
crab.shape
> (3072, )

crab.reshape((3, 32, 32))
crab.shape
> (3, 32, 32)

matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(crab)
> TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

When I try to plot this using matplotlib, I get the following error: `Invalid dimensions for image data`

Am I incorrectly sizing this image? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: (3,32,32) sounds good, now plot crab[0],crab[1],crab[2] next to each other, those are the color channels.   
In general, use type() to test the type of what you have, and compare to what input the function desires.

Comment: `imshow` only takes a single channel of 2D data, so the error is completely expected. Try just an array of (32x32), as in crab[0] etc.

Comment: Why don't you crop the image (with slicing ) to a size that can be posted ?  `crab5= crab[:,:5,:5]`e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Try reshaping as 32 x 32 x 3:

```
crab.reshape((32, 32, 3))
```

Now this may not result in the correct image, depending on where the data comes from and in which order it has been saved, but it should fix the error you have shown.

If the image is not right, try plotting the bands one at a time to figure out which image plane corresponds to which index.